# What's considered "spam"?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Constitutes Spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21823/what-constitutes-spam)

After looking around, I'm a bit confused... is an answer like this considered spam?

[How does free know how much to free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518711/c-programming-how-does-free-know-how-much-to-free/1520271#1520271)

Why or why not?

(I guess it's "advertising" in some sense, but it seems relevant...)

Comment: That's primarily a bad answer.

Comment: possible dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21823/what-constitutes-spam

Comment: @Daniel: Very interesting link... it's indeed hard for me to say whether that's spam or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it has 8 downvotes and gets closed by user flags then, yes, it is definitely spam.  And of course, a "free course on iTunes University" doesn't have anything to do with the free() function.  I can't imagine that diploma looks good on your wall.

EDIT: as Brad points out in the comments, "iTunes University" is just a daft name for a video sharing site and not actually an accredited institute of learning that hands out diplomas that look good on the wall.  And, presumably, all videos are free, maybe some even talk about free() as unlikely as that sounds.  Easy mistake, got me, this answer wasn't actually spam.

Comment: I have to disagree about this being spam.  I saw the flags and didn't really understand them.  It's a bad answer, yes, but iTunes U is merely a video hosting service that Apple provides to universities so that they can make their courses freely available.  Two semesters of a course I taught are hosted there.  I'm thinking he saw something in one of videos for the course he describes relating to memory management, but explained himself very poorly in his answer.  His other answers also don't do anything more to promote this course or the iTunes U service.

Comment: Did you just spam iTunes University in a comment?

Comment: No, just providing a reason why I don't think the spam flag applies to this question. He was not promoting iTunes U any more than someone who mentions a series of videos on YouTube could be considered to be promoting that service.  It was a bad answer, but the spam flags were taking things a bit too far.

Comment: Oooops, sorry for flagging your comment.  Not really.  Post updated.

Comment: No problem, it's an easy thing to get mixed up due to Apple's branding on this and all of the spammy online universities out there.